# How to Use a Shell Script to Modify the job.properties file and run an Oozie script?

Tags: shell, hadoop, hdfs, oozie

I have an Oozie workflow that essentially

```
1. Sqoops from Oracle to HDFS
2. Runs MapReduce on the Data
3...
```

I would like to be able to run a shell script to pass in a where clause for use in the Sqoop action.

```
./run.sh "birth_date < TO_DATE(...)"
```

I would like this to pass a parameter to the `job.properties` file configuring the Oozie Sqoop parameter which gets passed to the work flow.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can have a `job.properties_template` file where you will have a line such as

```
sqoop-where-arg=WHERE_PLACEHOLDER
```

Then in your `run.sh` script you will simply replace the placeholder and generate the actual job.properties file:

```
sed "s/WHERE_PLACEHOLDER/$1/" < job.properties_template > job.properties
```

You can then run the Oozie workflow using the newly generated `job.properties` file.

Does it answer your question?